# Struts project with DynaValidatorForm gives HTTP status 500 error - "Resources cannot be null"

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts

I'm learning Struts and I've created a project with maven + hibernate + Struts.. When I run the project the JSP loads but when I submit the data, it gives me the following error -

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resources cannot be null.

I tried my best but I cannot find what's wrong with it. Below are my source codes.

Web.xml :-

```
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Customer.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Struts-config.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"        "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="customerActionForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
            <form-property name="name" type="java.lang.String"></form-property>
            <form-property name="age" type="java.lang.String"></form-property>
            <form-property name="contactNo" type="java.lang.String"></form-property>
            <form-property name="email" type="java.lang.String"></form-property>
        </form-bean>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
    <action path="/register" name="customerActionForm" parameter="parameter" type="com.openarc.struts.action.CustomerAction" input="Customer.jsp">
        <forward name="success" path="index.jsp"></forward>
    </action>
</action-mappings>

<message-resources parameter="errors"/>
```

errors.properties (used before for validator framework)

```
label.name = Name
label.age = Age
label.contactNo = Contact Number
label.email = Email
```

Customer.jsp :-

```
<body>
    <html:form action="register">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><bean:message key="label.name"/> </td>
                <td><html:text property="name"></html:text></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><bean:message key="label.age"/> </td>
                <td><html:text property="age"></html:text></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><bean:message key="label.contactNo"/> </td>
                <td><html:text property="contactNo"></html:text></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><bean:message key="label.email"/> </td>
                <td><html:text property="email"></html:text></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><html:submit property="parameter" value="Create Customer"></html:submit> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </html:form>
</body>
```

CustomerAction.java :-

```
public class CustomerAction extends DispatchAction{

    public ActionForward createCustomer(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        DynaActionForm dynaForm = (DynaActionForm)form;

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomerId(1);
        customer.setName(dynaForm.getString("name"));
        customer.setAge(Short.parseShort(dynaForm.getString("age")));
        customer.setContactNo(dynaForm.getString("contactNo"));
        customer.setEmail(dynaForm.getString("email"));

        CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAO();
        customerDAO.createCustomer(customer);

        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

CustomerDAO.java :-

```
public class CustomerDAO {

    public Customer createCustomer(Customer customer){
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try{
            Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(customer);
            session.flush();
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            HibernateUtil.closeSession();
        }
        return customer;
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java :-

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory SESSIONFACTORY = createSessionFactory();
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> THREADLOCAL = new ThreadLocal<Session>();

    private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        try{
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
             System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
             throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static Session openSession(){
        Session session = THREADLOCAL.get();
        if(session == null){
            session = SESSIONFACTORY.openSession();
            THREADLOCAL.set(session);
        }
        return session;
    }

    public static void closeSession(){
        Session session = THREADLOCAL.get();
        if(session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
            THREADLOCAL.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems a famous error when I search the internet, but I cannot find what exactly is wrong with my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add plugin below the content of  `struts-config.xml`. Hope it will solve your issue.

```
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
<set-property
property="pathnames"
value="/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml,
/WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
</plug-in>
```

And don't forget to initial `validation.xml` file in `/WEB-INF/validation.xml`

Comment: I knew that plugin before. But sorry, I'm not using validator framework now, for this project.. Anyways I gave it a try but it only causes a 404 error for the "register.do" path when I submit the data.

Comment: you need a initial 'validation.xml' file in '/WEB-INF/validation.xml;.